# with fixed width body how can I get a <div> with wide content to float:left?

Tags: html

I have

```
body {
   width: 1000px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto
}
```

in order for the contents to be centered. I am looking for a way to have text links like this:

```
JAZZ | ROCK | COUNTRY | WORLD | POP | GOSPEL | R&B | HIP HOP | CLASSICAL | REGGAE
```

show on two or three lines when the browser's width is resized to less than the width of these text links - I tried `float:left` and or `min-width:400px` but these do not work.

It is probably obvious but I haven't figured out how to do it.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
   float: left;//Add float left
   height: 100px;//Set height of div
   width: 1000px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto
}
```

Hope this helped buddy :)

Comment: thanks - it does work with those links flowing to two or three lines when the browser width is made smaller - but the overall content isn't centered - probably can't center it when using float:left